# Adjusting Magnification Step Size with Keyboard Shortcuts in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, dconf, zooming

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I'm reaching out for assistance regarding the magnification feature in Ubuntu, specifically when using the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> for zoom in, <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> for zoom out). My objective is to adjust the step size for magnification to increase or decrease by a factor of 0.15 with each key press, instead of the default behavior which zooms in or out by 1x.

**What I Have Tried:**

- **GNOME Tweaks and dconf Editor**: I looked into GNOME Tweaks and the dconf Editor for any settings related to magnification step size but found none that directly affect the keyboard shortcut behavior.
- **gsettings Command**: I have also explored using `gsettings` to see if there's a way to adjust the magnification step size. While I can change the default magnification factor (`org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor`), this only sets the default zoom level and does not influence the incremental changes made with the keyboard shortcuts.
- **Research for Workarounds**: I have searched for potential workarounds, including custom scripts or third-party tools, but I haven't found a solution that specifically addresses adjusting the magnification step size through keyboard shortcuts.

**My Question to the Community:**
Has anyone successfully modified the step size for magnification using keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu? If so, could you share how you achieved this? Alternatively, if there's a script or a third-party tool that facilitates this adjustment, I'd appreciate learning about it.

Adjusting the magnification step size is crucial for my workflow, and I believe having finer control over this feature could benefit others who rely on Ubuntu's accessibility features.

Thank you in advance for any guidance or suggestions you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to be able to zoom in/out using a more  granular zoom factor.  With the help of the following article, I was able to set my own zoom incremental change factor using a combination of `gsettings` and `xbindkeys`.

https://superuser.com/questions/1532190/gnome-3-shortcut-for-super-mouse-wheel

Basically, I use this command to zoom in by 1%:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor $(echo $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor) \* 1.01 | bc -l)`

And use the following to decrease the zoom out by 1%:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor $(echo v=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor) / 1.01\; if \(v\<1.0\) v=1.0\; v | bc -l)`

Then use `xbindkeys` to bind your desired zoom in/out shortcuts to the above commands.  I binded the more granular zoom in/out to a new set of shortcuts.  That way, I can do quick zoom in/out using the original keys and then use mine to fine tune.

If you don't have `xbindkeys` already installed, see the following for details.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xbindkeys

Hope this helps,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, but the solution does require some technical experience to set up. Perhaps I should write a proper blog post for it. But in (sadly) short:

I ended up using `xbindkeys`, `lua`, and `dconf`, combined with the following scripts to give me the ability to zoom in/out like you used to in compiz/macos. You can press `Super` + `Alt` + Mouse scroll wheel to zoom in and out.

First, make sure you have the screen magnifier enabled. You can do this with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `8`. You can also change the settings using `dconf`, its in `/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/magnifier`.

Here is the file I put in `~/.xbindkeys.scm`:

```
(xbindkey-function '(mod4 alt b:4)
           (lambda ()
             (run-command "zin")))

(xbindkey-function '(mod4 alt b:5)
           (lambda ()
             (run-command "zout")))
```

Next I make files `zin` and `zout` and put it bin, I wrote them with lua:

`~/bin/zin`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local f = io.popen('dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/magnifier/mag-factor')
local z = f:read("*n")
f:close()
local z = math.min(z*1.05, 20)
os.execute(string.format("dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/magnifier/mag-factor %f", z))
```

`~/bin/zout`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

local f = io.popen('dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/magnifier/mag-factor')
local z = f:read("*n")
f:close()
local z = math.max(z/1.05, 1)
os.execute(string.format("dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/magnifier/mag-factor %f", z))
```

Finally, add `xbindkeys_autostart` to your `Startup Applications` menu and restart (or just start `xbindkeys` from the terminal if you want to test it out.)

## Alternate (possibly simpler) solution

You can do all of this within one file using just `.xbindkeys.scm`, but I found that it caused xbindkeys to segfault, so you'd probably end up doing more work anyway. But if anyone can get it to work, here is the base file:

```
(define mag 1)
(define MIN-MAG 1)
(define MAX-MAG 20)
(define STEP 0.05)

(define (set-mag val)
  (run-command (string-append "dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/magnifier/mag-factor "
                  (number->string val))))

(xbindkey-function '(mod4 alt b:4)
           (lambda ()
             (set! mag (min (+ mag (* mag STEP)) MAX-MAG))
             (set-mag mag)))

(xbindkey-function '(mod4 alt b:5)
           (lambda ()
             (set! mag (max (- mag (* mag STEP)) MIN-MAG))
             (set-mag mag)))
```